# Why LaTeX is the winner?

Tags: programming-tools

When `LaTeX` was LaTeX 2.09, AMSTeX seemed for me to be deeper. Tools for a beautiful math were advanced and the manual by Michael Spivak reminded in its beauty *The TeXbook*. But LaTeX have won and now AMSTeX macros are only additional packages.

What is the source of such a success? I am afraid that I am still missing some LaTeX subtleties, hence this question. Reasons I can quess are labelling system and many packages even about twenty years ago, but it is not enough for me to understand the source of this success.

*Remark:* And it seems that there is a local threshold: 50000 questions.

Comment: amstex was better at maths, but less flexible for everything else, so once latex had the ams packages, and broadly equivalent math formatting, the benefits swung in favour of latex. But really historical winners/loses are always accidents of history there is not necessarily any technical reason.

Comment: Mike Spivak tried to sell LAMS-TeX which sported automatic cross references; but nobody (or very few people) bought it. In the meantime, Schöpf and Mittelbach ported AMS-TeX to LaTeX.